# update with decode is not working, why does null data input?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update x1 a set (a.cd)= 
 (select distinct(decode(b.cd1,null,a.cd,b.cd1)) 
     from x2 b where b.nm(+)=a.nm 
                and d.nm2(+)=a.nm2
```

if `b.cd1` data is `null`, `a.cd` input `a.cd`, but I operate this sql, `null` data enter in `a.cd` but when I operate only subquery, it work well so i don't know why this problem happen

can you help me?

Comment: decode treats two null's as equal, so it will return first null encountered, if b.cd1 is null. Perhaps you need [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617
)?

Comment: In your code you have d.nm2 .. ??   there is not a table d

Comment: Your query is syntactically wrong and it is not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Also, what does `d.nm2` represent?

Comment: i'm sorry d.nm2 is mistake, it is b.nm2

Comment: `decode(b.cd1,null,a.cd,b.cd1)` is a complicated way to write `nvl(b.cd1,a.cd)` or `coalesce(b.cd1,a.cd)`.

Comment: Unrelated but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a`

Answer (score 0):

How about phrasing this like this?

```
update x1 a
    set a.cd = (select b.cd1
                from x2 b
                where b.nm = a.nm and b.nm2 = a.nm2
--------------------------------------^ assume you intend b here
               )
    where (select b.cd1
           from x2 b
           where b.nm = a.nm and b.nm2 = a.nm2
          ) is not null;
```

That is, only update the rows where the value is not `NULL`.